# Mapbox geocoder in React

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, geocoder

I recently made my first app on React. I had a d3 map that looks a bit old now, so I decided to switch to Mapbox.
The data transmitted is a list of country names and a percentage. The goal is to visualize each country and its percentage.
I wrote all my code, and everything seemed to go well.
However, I now get this error on line 19 : "Geocoder is not defined".
I specify that I have installed :

- mapbox-gl
- react-mapbox-gl
- react-map-gl-geocoder
  Can someone explain to me where my mistake came from?

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import mapboxgl from "mapbox-gl";
import MapGeocoder from "react-map-gl-geocoder";

const MapChart = ({ data }) => {
  const mapContainer = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    mapboxgl.accessToken =
      "**********";
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: mapContainer.current,
      style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v12",
      center: [0, 0],
      zoom: 1
    });

    // Geocode the data points to get the latitude and longitude
    const geocoder = new MapGeocoder({
      accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken
    });

    data.forEach((datapoint) => {
      geocoder.geocode(datapoint.country, (error, result) => {
        if (error) {
          console.error(error);
          return;
        }

        const [longitude, latitude] = result.features[0].geometry.coordinates;

        const marker = new mapboxgl.Marker({
          color: "#" + ((Math.random() * 0xffffff) << 0).toString(16)
        }).setLngLat([longitude, latitude]);
        marker.setPopup(
          new mapboxgl.Popup().setHTML(`
            <h3>${datapoint.country}</h3>
            <p>${datapoint.percentage}%</p>
          `)
        );
        marker.addTo(map);
      });
    });
  }, [data]);

  return <div ref={mapContainer} style={{ width: "100%", height: "400px" }} />;
};

export default MapChart;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are actually using the MapboxGeocoder from '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder'. If you intend to use the one provided by react-map-gl-geocoder, it would work slightly differently.